# red5 v0.9: connect from red5 to zend_amf

Tags: red5, zend-amf

I want to be able to connect from red5 to php's Zend_Amf in order to send commands and perform operations. how can i do so? can anyone please pinpoint me to any information available on the subject.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work out-of-the-box, just make sure you have the "gateway" servlet enabled in your red5 application. Also since red5 doesn't run http on port 80 by default, make sure your php calls on port 5080 instead. You can find more information here: http://wiki.red5.org/wiki/Documentation/UsersReferenceManual/GettingStarted/03-Migration-Guide under the "Remoting" section.